# Need to slide one DIV on another DIV. Using only CSS

Tags: html, css

There should be a simple solution, but I can't work one out. I need div with class of ***geltona*** to slide onto div with class of ***zydra***. I must use only css, but I can't. It might be obvious, but I can't find a solution as I am only using floats and % in width and height, so I can't really set a location where it should go by keyframes.

```css
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

p {
 margin: 10px;
}

.header {
 height: 5%;
 width: 100%;
}


.geltona {
 height: 15%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: yellow;
 float: left;
}

.zydra {
 height: 15%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: lightblue;
 float: right;
}

.balta {
 height: 30%;
 width: 70%;
 background-color: white;
 float: left;
}

.juoda {
 height: 75%;
 width: 30%;
 background-color: black;
 float: right;
}

.oranzine {
 height: 20%;
 width: 35%;
 background-color: orange;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}

.melyna {
 position: relative;
 height: 45%;
 width: 35%;
 background-color: blue;
 float: right;
}

.zalia {
 height: 25%;
 width: 35%;
 background-color: green;
 float: left;
}

.ruda {
 height: 5%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: brown;
 float: left;
}




/*  ANIMACIJOS  */
/* 3. Blokas animuotai nukeliauja ant gretimo bloko, pilnai uždengęs gretimą bloką – išnyksta */



/* 20. Pasisuka nuo 45 laipsnių iki 0 laipsnių ir padidėja 30%; */

.zalia:hover {
 animation: sukasi 3s;
}

@keyframes sukasi {
 0%{transform: rotate(45deg)}
 100%{transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3)};
}



/* 21. Nuotrauka atslenka iš viršaus ir mažėja (trukmė 5 sec); */

.header img {
 position: absolute;
    top: -145px;
    max-width: 145px;
    max-height: 145px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: 5s;
}

.header:hover img {
    transition: 5s;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 45px;
    max-height: 45px;
}





/*  MEDIA QUERIES  */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (max-height: 1024px){

 .geltona {
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
 }

 .zydra {
  display: none;
 }

 .balta {
  height: 20%;
  width: 70%;
 }

 .juoda {
  height: 65%;
  width: 30%;
 }

 .oranzine {
  display: none;
 }

 .melyna {
  height: 45%;
  width: 40%;
 }

 .zalia {
  height: 45%;
  width: 30%;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>IPP Kursinis</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" content="initial-scale=1">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="header">
   <img src="img/foto.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="geltona"></div>

  <div class="zydra"
    id="keiciamaSpalva" 
       onmouseover="changeBackground(this.id, 'red', 'yellow');" 
       onmouseout="changeBackground(this.id, 'lightblue', 'black');">
     <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="balta"
       id="balta" 
      onmouseover="showClass();"
      onmouseout="removeClass();">
  </div>

  <div class="juoda"></div>

  <div class="oranzine"></div>

  <div class="melyna">
   <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="zalia"></div>

  <div class="ruda"></div>




  <!-- JAVASCRIPT prasideda nuo čia -->

  <script type="text/javascript">

   /* Keičiama teksto ir fono spalva pagal nurodymus. */
    function changeBackground(id, color, textColor) {

      document.getElementById(id).style.background = color;
      document.getElementById(id).style.color = textColor;

    };




    /* Parodome bloko klasę ir ją ištriname, kad nesipildytų visas blokas*/

    function showClass() { 

      var element = document.getElementById('balta');
      element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "<p> Šio bloko klasė: "+element.className+"</p>";


 };

 function removeClass() {

  document.getElementById('balta').innerHTML = "";

 };




 /* Rodoma lango, ekrano ir slankiklių informacija, tik tuomet, kai keičiame ekrano dydį. */

 window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
    function displayWindowSize(){

   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
   "Ekrano plotis: " + screen.width + "<br>" +
   "Ekrano aukštis: " + screen.height + "<br>" +
   "Lango plotis: " + window.innerWidth + "<br>" +
   "Lango aukštis: " + window.innerHeight + "<br>" +
   "Slankiklio horizontali padėtis: " + window.scrollX + "<br>" +
   "Slankiklio vertikali padėtis: " + window.scrollY;

 };

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean slide, like when hovered to slide on the lightblue container?

Comment: @Highdef Yes! When yellow div is hovered it shoud start to slide to other side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the least amount of changes for this code, I came up with this.

Wrap your two neighbouring containers (**geltona** and **zydra**) in another container (**gelzy** here) and give it the `position:relative` and the two child containers the `position:absolute` with `left:0 and right:0` instead of the `floats`.

Make use of the *transition on **hover*** to move the **geltona** (with *higher z-index*)to **50% of the left** to overlap on the blue container

```
.gelzy{
position:relative;
height:15%;
width:100%;
}

.geltona {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  transition:left 1s ease-in-out;
}

.zydra {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
}

.geltona:hover {
  left:50%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  margin: 10px;
}

.header {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
}

.gelzy{
position:relative;
height:15%;
width:100%;
}

.geltona {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  left:0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:2;
  transition:left 1s ease-in-out;
}

.zydra {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  right:0;
  position: absolute;
}

.geltona:hover {
  left:50%;
}

.balta {
  height: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

.juoda {
  height: 75%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: black;
  float: right;
}

.oranzine {
  height: 20%;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.melyna {
  position: relative;
  height: 45%;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
}

.zalia {
  height: 25%;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
}

.ruda {
  height: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  float: left;
}


/*  ANIMACIJOS  */


/* 3. Blokas animuotai nukeliauja ant gretimo bloko, pilnai uždengęs gretimą bloką – išnyksta */


/* 20. Pasisuka nuo 45 laipsnių iki 0 laipsnių ir padidėja 30%; */

.zalia:hover {
  animation: sukasi 3s;
}

@keyframes sukasi {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(45deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1.3)
  }
  ;
}


/* 21. Nuotrauka atslenka iš viršaus ir mažėja (trukmė 5 sec); */

.header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -145px;
  max-width: 145px;
  max-height: 145px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 5s;
}

.header:hover img {
  transition: 5s;
  top: 0;
  max-width: 45px;
  max-height: 45px;
}


/*  MEDIA QUERIES  */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (max-height: 1024px) {
  .geltona {
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .zydra {
    display: none;
  }
  .balta {
    height: 20%;
    width: 70%;
  }
  .juoda {
    height: 65%;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .oranzine {
    display: none;
  }
  .melyna {
    height: 45%;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .zalia {
    height: 45%;
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>IPP Kursinis</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" content="initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/foto.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="gelzy">
  <div class="geltona"></div>

  <div class="zydra" id="keiciamaSpalva" onmouseover="changeBackground(this.id, 'red', 'yellow');" onmouseout="changeBackground(this.id, 'lightblue', 'black');">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="balta" id="balta" onmouseover="showClass();" onmouseout="removeClass();">
  </div>

  <div class="juoda"></div>

  <div class="oranzine"></div>

  <div class="melyna">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>

  <div class="zalia"></div>

  <div class="ruda"></div>




  <!-- JAVASCRIPT prasideda nuo čia -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
    /* Keičiama teksto ir fono spalva pagal nurodymus. */
    function changeBackground(id, color, textColor) {

      document.getElementById(id).style.background = color;
      document.getElementById(id).style.color = textColor;

    };




    /* Parodome bloko klasę ir ją ištriname, kad nesipildytų visas blokas*/

    function showClass() {

      var element = document.getElementById('balta');
      element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + "<p> Šio bloko klasė: " + element.className + "</p>";


    };

    function removeClass() {

      document.getElementById('balta').innerHTML = "";

    };




    /* Rodoma lango, ekrano ir slankiklių informacija, tik tuomet, kai keičiame ekrano dydį. */

    window.onresize = displayWindowSize;

    function displayWindowSize() {

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
        "Ekrano plotis: " + screen.width + "<br>" +
        "Ekrano aukštis: " + screen.height + "<br>" +
        "Lango plotis: " + window.innerWidth + "<br>" +
        "Lango aukštis: " + window.innerHeight + "<br>" +
        "Slankiklio horizontali padėtis: " + window.scrollX + "<br>" +
        "Slankiklio vertikali padėtis: " + window.scrollY;

    };
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```